# first path segment in URL cannot contain colon error in gitrunner register

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I have tried various ways which is available on stack overflow but not single one works .i was  getting error everytime whenever i tried to register my gitlab runner everytime please provide descriptive answer

error: first path segment in URL cannot contain colon error

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide a description of your setup, it is hard to pin down the problem. I'm also not an expert on GitLab and I just recently started tinkering around with my own local GitLab instance installed via Docker.

For me I wanted to connect a GitLab-Runner to my GitLab in the local network. That's where I tumbled upon the error you are mentioning. I am using a different port for the GitLab server, which was neccessary because some other services are already using the default ports. The solution for me was to add the prefix `http://` in front of the ip. After that, the registration went flawlessly.
So instead of writing for example

```
 123.456.789.XXX:YYYY
```

I had to write

```
http://123.456.789.XXX:YYYY
```

Of course the ip can be different according to your network.

If you provide more information, it would be easier to solve your problem.
And in case you solved it on your own, feel free to share your solution.